# Passed Value after Filtering is 0 - Primefaces

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using currently Primefaces 6.1 and i got following Datatable:

```
<prime:column headerText="Status" filterBy="#{zoneAccSum.statusImage(zoneAccess.request.id)}"  
    filterMatchMode="equals">
        <f:facet name="filter">
            <prime:selectOneButton styleClass="theme-running" onchange="PF('data').filter()" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{zoneAccSum.statusButtons}" />   
           </prime:selectOneButton>
        </f:facet>
     <prime:graphicImage value="#{zoneAccSum.statusImage(zoneAccess.request.id)}" />    
</prime:column>

<prime:column headerText="Details" style="text-align:center; width:150px;">
    <prime:commandButton value="Details" id="ajax" actionListener="#{zoneAccSum.redirect(zoneAccess.id)}" oncomplete="PF('requestModal').show()" update="SummaryFormZone:zone" />
</prime:column>
```

So the filtering just works fine, it shows me the right result. But if i use the commandButton after filtering, the passed value I get is always 0. To clarify i got my Bean already ViewScoped and Serialized and my Button sets an Value in Bean where my Modal Panel can request it's data from.

Does anyone know, how i can fix getting 0 all the time or how i can build a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I tried couple of things today and figured it finally out myself. For other people who might encounter this i will post my solution here:

Primefaces somehow needs an extra List in the Managed Bean for Filter purposes. So at the first datatable tag, you need to add following:

```
<prime:dataTable var="zoneAccess" value="#{zoneAccSum.data}" widgetVar="data" rows="10" paginator="true" filteredValue="#{zoneAccSum.filteredData}">
```

The filteredValue tag

In your Managed Bean just add a new list with the with the given name, in this case filteredData, and Primefaces now no longer will pass null values